# Pipe search pattern to BSD grep

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, bsd

I have this command string which worked perfectly well in OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) (which tells me its grep is grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1)...

```
$ grep -hi 'TERM' file1.txt | cut -d '|' -f 3 | grep -f - file2.txt
```

(Finding all lines with TERM in them in file1, cutting each down to the unique ID number in field 3, then looking up those IDs in file2)

And yet this fails in OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) (which tells me its grep is grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD)...

```
grep: -: No such file or directory
```

I really don't want to install GNU grep on this machine. Is there a way to fix the second grep command so BSD grep will work? Or a better way to go about it generally?

Some sample code:

file1.txt would look like:

```
Jones Inc||000123||foo||bar 
TerminatorLLC||000124||foo||bar
Conan LP||000125||foo||bar
Termites-R-Us||000126||foo||bar
```

file2.txt like:

```
000123||210 Main Street||moo||car
000124||Los Angeles||moo||car
000125||Mythical Kingdom||moo||car
000126||Your Woodwork||moo||car
```

Answer (score 3):

`-` usually refers to stdin or stdout, `-f` will search B for lines from A:

```
grep -f A B
```

`<(...)` (called [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)) will make a "file" with the output of `...`:

```
% echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

You can with this knowledge change the commands to:

```
grep -f <(grep -hi 'TERM' file1.txt | cut -d '|' -f 3) file2.txt
```

And in AWK:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR == FNR { if ( /[tT][eE][rR][mM]/ ) a[$3] = 1; next }a[$1]' file1.txt file2.txt
```

And alternative as suggested by [@fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui), but modified to not use [gawk's `IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html). Note that the files are read `file2.txt` `file1.txt`

```
awk -F'|' 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $0; next } /[tT][eE][rR][mM]/ { print a[$3] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this grep pattern. It does work with either GNU or BSD grep. Both files are about 750k lines. GNU grep finished in 33 seconds; BSD grep has been running for 4 minutes and still hasn't shown me the first result. If nothing else, your so kindly provided code has convinced me that BSD grep is crap.

Comment: The awk from @ andlrc seems to work but the one from @fedorqui does not seem to.

Comment: @fedorqui I appreciate the time you spent on this. But even after rechecking that file2 precedes file 1... it doesn't seem to work.